# Is there a 'DetailView' in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I know there is a change/update view in Django admin but is there any detail view that just lists out the record's attributes? Kind of like the DetailView in the Django app?

Or does anyone know any 3rd party packages I can install to provide the same functionality?

Comment: You can check it from https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/adding-custom-views-or-templates-to-django-admin-740640cc6d42

Comment: you can make the fields readonly or you can give the user view access only

Comment: @HenryM, I still want the user to be able to access the change view. But I want another view where a user can see more information about a record. For example, if a table has 12 columns, it would be weird to show them all in the list view. If there was a detail view, the information (incl. related records) could easily be displayed there

Comment: @PallaviSharma, thanks for this. I know I can create custom views. It just seems strange that there's no dedicated detail view and I couldn't find 3rd party modules for it. Made me feel like I was missing something

Answer (score 0):

I too was investigating this recently.

One approach that works is to create a custom `ModelAdmin` with a detail_view method that forwards the call to `ModelAdmin`'s `changeform_view()` method. Then this view is added to the urls list via overriding `ModelAdmin.get_urls()`.

Then, in this method set a class attribute, say __detail_view to True. Then override `has_change_permission()` method, which returns False, if __detail_view is detected and set to True. This will cause AdminSite to render the fields in readonly mode (using the AdminReadonlyField wrapper fields) instead of the standard AdminField objects.

You can also change the change_form_template to a custom template for detail_view to accommodate custom rendering for detail views.

```
class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    if getattr(self, '__detail_view', None):
       return False
    return super().has_change_permission(request, obj)

  def detail_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    setattr(self, '__detail_view', True)
    # Custom template for detail view
    org_change_form_template = self.change_form_template
    self.change_form_template = self.detail_view_template or self.change_form_template
    ret = self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    self.change_form_template = org_change_form_template
    delattr(self, '__detail_view')
    return ret

  def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    # add detail-view for the object
    from django.urls import path

    def wrap(view):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper.model_admin = self
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

    info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
    # Replace the backwards compatibility (Django<1.9) change view
    # for the detail view.
    urls[len(urls)-1] = path('<path:object_id>/', wrap(self.detail_view), name='%s_%s_detail' % info)
    return urls
```

I haven't tried the custom template approach, but using the `__detail_view` object attribute to force readonly rending seems to work.

The default change_form_template still shows the delete button at the bottom, which is okay I guess. But it needs another button to actually take you to the real change page where the object can be changed. Again template customization is the way to go here. Hint: look at `{% submit_row %}` in admin templates and model a custom inclusion template tag that displays the Change button, if the user has change permission. Take note to call the `has_change_permission()` here to get the real permission before setting the `__detail_view` attribute.

Not sure if there are other implications for doing it this way, but it ought to work.

HTH