# View detailed view of model item directly in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Django shows list of model items in admin panel, but don't want to show the list but I directly want to show the detail view . How can i do this ?

Comment: Do you want List of Details Views for your model items?

Comment: Like in the admin panel, when we click on a model then we get to see the list of items . But instead of the list , i want to view detail view there .

Comment: Ok but what if your model has hundreds and thousands of instances?

Comment: I want the direct detail view for model with single item . For , more than 1 instances i wanted to show the list of detail views . But for now , i only want this for model with single item .

Comment: I don't think it's good idea because if you just click on the item in the list you will see detail by default, but anyway see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166494/4915008

Comment: Please use the search before posting and take a look here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166494/4915008